# Render every subdocuments of all documents with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user model and a pet model, using Mongoose.

user model :

```
  var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     email        : String,
     password     : String,
     pets         : [Pet.schema]

   });

   module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

pet model :

```
   var petSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name         : String
    });

   module.exports = mongoose.model('Pet', petSchema);
```

I'd like to render all the pets of all users in a page. I tried to do :

```
    app.get('/pets', function(req, res) {

    Pet.find({}, function(err, pets){

       res.render('pets.ejs', {"pets":pets});

    });
});
```

But I only get an empty array [ ].

How could I get every Pets ?

More generally, I will have to use Pet model independently from the User. Should I change the way my models are constructed ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to embed the `Pet` sub document and use as if it weren't embedded.

First, if you're doing embedded, you need to define the schema for Pet before you use it (create it first). If you're embedding, you can't do a find on the Model for pets that way.

[Mongoose Subdocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

If, instead, you want to store a reference to a `Pet` inside a `User`, you need to store its `ObjectId`.

```
pets : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Pet"}]
```

You would then likely use [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to fill the `pets` property at run time.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Indeed, I have to change my model and make a reference.